# Camel - Load csv file into database - Include date in the filename as an extra column

Tags: hibernate, csv, gradle, apache-camel

I am trying to write an ETL process in Camel to load a csv file into the database. There will be a new file everyday in a specific remote location which I can access through sftp. In order to simplify the problem now I assume that this folder is local and can be accessed using the file component from camel.

The file name contains the creation date and I want to extract and add that as an extra column into the database. 
i.e. filename is "FileA-20140224.csv".

I would like to use hibernate.

Could you please give me a better idea on how I can achieve that with Camel and help me with the set up?

How can I load a file into the db and populate the extra column that is not included in the file?

```
private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:/.?include=FileA-20140224.csv")
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${file:name}")
               .convertBodyTo(FileData.class)
               .to("jpa:com.domain.entity.FileData");
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement it is the following.

```
private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:/.?include=FileA-20140224.csv")
                   .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${file:name}")
                   .unmarshal()
                   .bindy(BindyType.Csv, FileData.class)
                   .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            String fileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameOnly");
                            // extract date from file name

                            List<FileData> data = (List<FileData>) exchange.getIn().getBody();

                            // go through the stream and set the extra column equal to the extracted date from the filename
                           // dataDao.save(data);
                                                    }
                    })
        }
    }
```

In order to use bindy you have to annotate the FileData with @CsvRecord and each field that is included in the file with @DataField.